# Thinking Sphinx(v4.4) - Error while indexing after including 'where' condition in index definition

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Thinking sphinx gem version - 4.4.1
Sphinx version - 3.3.1

I get

> ERROR: index 'article_core': no full text fields in schema, nothing to index!

while indexing after including where condition in the index definition.

Index definition below

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :article, :with => :active_record do
  indexes title
  # where "text = 'Past Simple'" # type of text column is text: rebuild successful
  # where "id > 1" # type of id column is int: rebuild successful
  where "photo = 'photo'" # type of photo column is String : rebuild fails
end
```

1. The issue occurs when we use where condition inside the index
   definition on a string column(char varying)
2. This issue does not occur when we apply where condition with other data types.
3. the error statement is 'ERROR: index 'article_core': no full text fields in schema, nothing
   to index!.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering if you're using PostgreSQL as your application database? And maybe you don't have any articles which match the `where` condition? There's an issue with Sphinx 3.x releases where empty indices raise an error when indexing (and it seems it's not fixed in v3.3.1, which only came out last week).

I've [lodged this issue with the Sphinx team](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=2738), but there's not been any response thus far.

If you really want to use SQL-backed indices, I'm afraid you're going to have to downgrade to Sphinx 2.2.11, or consider switching to Manticore (a drop-in fork of Sphinx that doesn't have this issue). Or, you could instead use [real-time indices](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v4/real_time.html), which work fine with Sphinx v3. If so, you can use the `scope` method within an index to limit the results:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :article, :with => :real_time do
  indexes title

  scope { Article.where(:photo => "photo") }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this response, Pat. It did not occur to me that this could issue related to empty indices.